Using knex's onConflict().merge() is creating duplicate rows in my db?
Exactly as the title says. I've got a simple transaction that should determine whether a record exists already, and update it if an image url has changed. Otherwise, create a new record. It looks like this:
if (question.image_url) {
    // Update url if existing, otherwise create a new one
    await knex('table_getting_duplicated')
        .insert({
            one_Id: oneId,
            twoId: twoId,
            image_url: question.image_url
        })
        .onConflict(['one_id', 'two_id'])
        .merge({
            image_url: question.image_url
        });
}
        

Seems simple enough right? I use two IDs that are foreign keys as the conflict parameters. If there is a conflict, I just want to update the image_url and nothing else.
Instead, let's say I have 3 questions. 1 of them already has an image_url. I update a second question to also have an image url. When looping through the questions and this code is hit, it will create a duplicate row of the pre-existing question that already had a url in addition to adding the new one. I thought onConflict().merge() was supposed to take care of this?
I've had this split out previously to not use this upsert functionality, but I'd like to use it if possible as the logic gets unnecessarily complex.

As per Knex Docs , you have to use Primary Key or Unqiue index.
INFO from DOC

For PostgreSQL and SQLite, the column(s) specified by this method either be the table's PRIMARY KEY or have a UNIQUE index on them, or query will fail to execute. When specifying multiple columns, they must a composite PRIMARY KEY or have composite UNIQUE index. MySQL will the specified columns and always use the table's PRIMARY KEY. For platform support across PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite you must explicitly specify the columns in .onConflict() and those column(s) must be  the table's PRIMARY KEY.
